# Is it possible to use an image style with a path rather than a URI?

Tags: 8, media

I want to be able to send an image included in a custom module to the `image_style` theme like:

```
  $render_image = [
    '#theme' => 'image_style',
    '#style_name' => $imagecache_template,
    '#uri' => '/modules/custom/MYMODULE/default.png',
    ...
  ];
```

But '#uri' is expecting something in the format `public://` . Is it possible to marshall a relative path somehow?

Comment: It should be possible to create an image style derivative using an ImageStyle entity or the image.factory service, but I haven't tried it myself.

Answer (score 1):

I'll expand a bit on what acrosman answered, only because I needed this exact same thing so hopefully this will help the next person who comes across this.

I'm working from preprocess_page and using a view to grab my images.

Like his answer make sure you add the ImageStyle:

```
use Drupal\image\Entity\ImageStyle;
```

Once I grabbed the view entity I was able to narrow down my image field and then work my way to the styled image.

```
$image = $entity->get('field_images')->getValue();
$image_entity = File::load($image[0]['target_id']);
$image_uri = $image_entity->get('uri')->value;
$style = ImageStyle::load('my_image_style');
$image_url = $style->buildUrl($image_uri);
```

So overall my whole function to grab the image from a View and apply a custom image style looked like.

```
function _mytheme_preprocess_page_front_projects(array &$variables) {
  $projects = array();
  $view = Views::getView('projects');

  if (is_object($view)) {
    $view->setDisplay('page_1');
    $view->preExecute();
    $view->execute();

    foreach ($view->result as $k => $v) {
      $entity = $v->_entity;

      // Grab image entity.
      $image = $entity->get('field_images')->getValue();

      // Load the first value for preview image.
      $image_entity = File::load($image[0]['target_id']);

      // Grab the uri of that first image.
      $image_uri = $image_entity->get('uri')->value;

      // Using ImageStyle you then load your style.
      $style = ImageStyle::load('my_image_style');

      // Use buildUrl to create the path to your styled image.
      $image_url = $style->buildUrl($image_uri);

      // Then I return the url as an image variable to grab in page template.
      $projects[$k]['image'] = $image_url;
    }

    return $projects;
  }
}
```

Comment: this works well, don't forget to include `use Drupal\file\Entity\File;` before `File::load`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it from a render array, but you can load the ImageStyle entity and have it build a URL from a path using [`buildUrl()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21image%21src%21Entity%21ImageStyle.php/function/ImageStyle%3A%3AbuildUrl/8.2.x).

If you are doing this right in the .module file make sure to tell PHP you'll be using ImageStyle, in a plugin or controller you'll want to inject the class.

```
use Drupal\image\Entity\ImageStyle;
```

Then load you're style and build the URL (warning, I have not tested this):

```
$style = ImageStyle::load('img_style');
$image_path = $style->buildUrl('/modules/custom/MYMODULE/default.png');
```

From there you should be able to place that into whatever context you need to get the image rendered the way you'd like.